# Can Bitcoins or other coins be transferred back to US dollars?

Tags: sell-bitcoins

Can Bitcoins be transferred back to US Dollars?

Comment: You can't transform a pear into an apple, however, you can trade it.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin is just like anything else you can own.  You can buy it using any currency that a seller is willing to accept, and you can sell it for any currency you are willing to accept.  You aren't transferring, you are trading.  A bitcoin is always a bitcoin, and a dollar is always a dollar.  You simply need to exchange it with someone.